# javafx will cannot locate my .wav or .mp3 files

Tags: java, audio

I've been trying to play audio clips through Java and have had trouble using the javafx library. I've placed the sound files in my src folder and tried various ways of accessing them, and yet i get a NullPointerException each time I access them.

```
Media sound = new Media("file:beep.wav");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(sound);
player.play();
```

Another way i tried to access the file was

```
File f = new File("beep.wav");
Media sound = new Media(f.toString());
```

Also tried a few other things. When i do the system.out.print checks all filenames and paths print out correctly

I am running this on Ubuntu (Wily) 15.10, using Eclipse (Kepler) if that may help anyone help me

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tried that with no success.

I tried using the Clip method (shown below) and found that I encountered a memory error after playing a sound more than 20 times or so. after clearing out as much memory pertaining to the systems clip to fix the error i just decided it may be a driver issue since i was running on (32bit)Lubuntu and had to manually install a few drivers.

```
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip(null);
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
        clip.start(); //Clip.stop somewhere down the line
```

I then installed the newest release of (64bit)Ubuntu and the clip method has worked perfectly for me since.

Should I be doing any cleanup when using this method to avoid memory problems, or will external programs take care of that for me?

Thank you for your timely response.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run your program on text editing programs (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc) or tryingto run jar file?

In first case, try to place your audio file in your project folder. For example: C:/.../NetBeansProjects/MyPRoject/beep.wav , but declare it wihtout any folder names, like this

```
Something f = new Something("beep.wav"); // Something is not an Object XD
```

In second case, after clean-building place your audio file in dist folder of your project.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your sound files in a folder called 'sounds'.  The folder should be in your project folder at the same level as the src folder.  Then call the following method that takes the audio file name as a String argument.

```
    public void playSound (String musicFile){
    Media sound = new Media(new File("sounds/" + musicFile).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.play();
}

playSound("do.wav")
```